# Multiple BitmapFonts using one ttf file

Tags: libgdx

I try to load two *BitmapFonts* using an *AssetManager*

```
private void load(AssetManager assetManager) {
    FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
    assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
    assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

    assetManager.load(createDescriptor("myFont.ttf", 70, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK, 1););
    assetManager.load(createDescriptor("myFont.ttf", 50, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, 10););
}


public static AssetDescriptor createDescriptor(String fontPath, int fontSize, Color fontColor, Color borderColor, int borderSize) {
    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter parameter = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    parameter.fontFileName = fontPath;
    parameter.fontParameters.size = fontSize;
    parameter.fontParameters.color = fontColor;
    parameter.fontParameters.borderColor = borderColor;
    parameter.fontParameters.borderWidth = borderSize;
    return new AssetDescriptor<BitmapFont>(parameter.fontFileName, BitmapFont.class, parameter);
}
```

Unfortunately the *AssetManager* uses a method called *isLoaded* to ignore to load the second *BitmapFont* because of the same file name.

I would like to extend the *AssetManager* to not only check the filename but also check if the *AssetLoaderParameters* are equal. But the *AssetManager* does not want to be extended.

Is there another way to load multiple *BitmapFonts* using one *AssetManager* and one .ttf source file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the AssetDescriptor name and the fontFileName: fontFileName is the path to the *.ttf file. The name is unique for the asset. You could use myfont32 as a name for your font with a size of 32 and another one for other sizes.

Comment: Thank you! In my case I had to also add an .ttf to the AssetDescriptor name to avoid casting errors but now it works :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. I ran into this problem myself while using AssetManager ;).